# FirebaseUI with Firestore Recycler Options and custom adapter

Tags: java, android, firebaseui, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the FirebaseUI and a custom adapter to show data coming from Firestore database and storage, inside a list of Cards (on Samsung Galaxy S6 and S8 devices).

I was first using the method described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) (from the *firebase.google* webiste) but I then switched to [this one](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md) (from *firebase github*) as it is more suitable for my needs.

When I tried to see if data were coming from the server or the cache **with the first method**, the code below worked as expected:

```java
String source = snapshot != null && snapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()
            ? "Local" : "Server";
```

However, when using **the second method**, when I get my list of Snapshots, inside the adapter, from the query, and try to see if the data are coming from the server or the cache, I **always** get:

```
mSnapshots.getSnapshot(position).getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()
```

equal to `false`

and

```
mSnapshots.getSnapshot(position).getMetadata().isFromCache()
```

equal to `true`

independently of my internet connection.

Why? And how can I see if the data are coming from the server or the cache using the second method?

Thanks